# error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ppltasks.h': No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, c++-cx

When I attempt to compile my project, it gives the error:

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ppltasks.h': No such file or directory
```

What is `ppltasks.h`, and how do I find it?

Answer (score 3):

> error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ppltasks.h': No such file or directory

`ppltasks.h` is from [VC++ Component Extensions for Runtime Platforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xey702bw.aspx):

> Visual C++ provides language extensions to help you program against
>   runtime platforms. By using Visual C++ component extensions (C++/CX),
>   you can program Windows Store apps and components that compile to
>   native code. Although you can create Windows Store apps by programming
>   directly against the Windows Runtime COM interfaces, by using C++/CX,
>   you can work with constructors, exceptions, and other modern C++
>   programming idioms. To enable C++ programming in a managed execution
>   environment on the .NET platform, you can use C++/CLI.
>
> C++/CX is a subset of C++/CLI. For extensions that are common to
>   C++/CX and C++/CLI, the semantics depend on whether you are targeting
>   the common language runtime (CLR) or the Windows Runtime. To compile
>   your app to run on the Windows Runtime, specify the /ZW compiler
>   option. To compile it to run on the CLR, specify the /clr compiler
>   option. These switches are set automatically when you use Visual
>   Studio to create a project.

You should compile with `/ZW` or `/clr`.

If you are using them, then it sounds like your paths are not set properly. You need to ensure that, for example, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Metadata`, and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.0\Include\mscore` are on path.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when Build target is for a VS version that hasn't this header. Set it, for example, for vs120.